# How to include models in swagger ui

Tags: go, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a book API I built with golang, everything works just fine, I am trying to add swagger to it for the documentation, I have done it but I have a problem, i can only see the routes , but when i click on it, I can't see the descriptions, and i can't also see any information on the models,
here is my code on main.go

```
package main

import (
    //"fmt"
    "time"
    "github.com/cosimmichael/assessment/app/db_client"
    "github.com/cosimmichael/assessment/app/controllers"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"

    // "github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger"
    // "github.com/swaggo/files"

    //"github.com/swaggo/swag/example/celler/controller"
    //_ "github.com/swaggo/swag/example/celler/docs"
    _ "github.com/cosimmichael/assessment/app/docs"
    //"github.com/swaggo/swag/example/celler/httputil"

    swaggerFiles "github.com/swaggo/files"
    ginSwagger "github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger"


    // you need to import go mod  init for this parkage to work
    // "github.com/cosimmichael/assessment/app/strutil"
    // "github.com/cosimmichael/assessment/app/routers"
    // "net/http"
)

// @title Simple Book Dashboard API
// @version 1.0
// @description This is for book management.
// @termsOfService http://swagger.io/terms/

// @contact.name Books API Support
// @contact.url http://www.swagger.io/support
// @contact.email support@swagger.io

// @license.name Apache 2.0
// @license.url http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html

// @host localhost:3000
// @BasePath /api/v1/products
// @query.collection.format multi

// @securityDefinitions.basic BasicAuth

// @securityDefinitions.apikey ApiKeyAuth
// @in header
// @name Authorization, x-api-key

// @securitydefinitions.oauth2.application OAuth2Application
// @tokenUrl https://example.com/oauth/token
// @scope.write Grants write access
// @scope.admin Grants read and write access to administrative information

// @securitydefinitions.oauth2.implicit OAuth2Implicit
// @authorizationurl https://example.com/oauth/authorize
// @scope.write Grants write access
// @scope.admin Grants read and write access to administrative information

// @securitydefinitions.oauth2.password OAuth2Password
// @tokenUrl https://example.com/oauth/token
// @scope.read Grants read access
// @scope.write Grants write access
// @scope.admin Grants read and write access to administrative information

// @securitydefinitions.oauth2.accessCode OAuth2AccessCode
// @tokenUrl https://example.com/oauth/token
// @authorizationurl https://example.com/oauth/authorize
// @scope.admin Grants read and write access to administrative information

// @x-extension-openapi {"example": "value on a json format"}

func main(){
    db_client.InitialiseDBConnection()

    r := gin.Default()
    //r.Use(cors.Default())
    r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowOrigins:     []string{"http://localhost:8080"},
        AllowMethods:     []string{"PUT", "PATCH","POST","GET","DELETE"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{"Origin","Authorization","x-api-key","content-type"},
        ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        AllowOriginFunc: func(origin string) bool {
            return origin == "http://localhost:8080"
        },
        MaxAge: 12 * time.Hour,
    }))
    // router.HandleRoutes()
    r.POST("api/v1/products/login", controller.Login)
    r.POST("api/v1/products/create", controller.CreateProducts)
    r.GET("api/v1/products", controller.GetProducts)
    r.GET("api/v1/products/:id/show", controller.GetSingleProduct)
    r.PUT("api/v1/products/:id/update", controller.UpdateSingleProduct)
    r.DELETE("api/v1/products/:id/delete", controller.DeleteSingleProduct)
    //r.POST("api/v1/products/check", controller.CheckHeader)

    r.GET("/swagger/*any", ginSwagger.WrapHandler(swaggerFiles.Handler))

    if err := r.Run(":3000"); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    // router.HandleRoutes()
    // fmt.Println("Server Starting.. @ port :3000")
    // http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

here is my code on controller

```
package controller

import (
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/cosimmichael/assessment/app/db_client"
    "github.com/cosimmichael/assessment/app/model"
    // "github.com/swaggo/swag/example/celler/httputil"
    // "github.com/swaggo/swag/example/celler/model"
)


type testHeader struct {
    Token   string    `header:"x-api-key"`
}

// Login godoc
// @Summary Log in to admin account 
// @Description authentication
// @ID get-string-by-int
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  json
// @Param admin body Admin true "Add account"
 
// @Router /login [post]
func Login(c *gin.Context) {
    var reqBody model.Admin
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&reqBody); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid request body",
        })
        return
    }
    
    row := db_client.DBClient.QueryRow("SELECT id, username, password FROM admin WHERE username = ?;", reqBody.Username)
    var myAcc model.Admin

    if err := row.Scan(&myAcc.Id, &myAcc.Username, &myAcc.Password); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "something is wrong with request",
        })
        return
    }

    if myAcc.Password == reqBody.Password {
        c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{
            "error": false,
            "user": myAcc.Username,
            "token": "7b215b90-df8d-4077-8852-0907b0c1034e",
        })
        return
    }else{
        c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "invalid details",
        })
        return
    }

}
 
// CreateProducts godoc
// @Summary Create new book
// @Description saving new book detail
// @ID get-string-by-int
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  json
// @Param post body Post true "Add post"
 
// @Router /create [post]
func CreateProducts(c *gin.Context) {
    h := testHeader{}
    if err := c.ShouldBindHeader(&h); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Access denied",
        })
        return
    }
    if h.Token != "7b215b90-df8d-4077-8852-0907b0c1034e"{
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid Access",
        })
        return
    }
    var reqBody model.Post
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&reqBody); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid request body",
        })
        return
    }

    if reqBody.Title == ""{
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Insert product title",
        })
        return
    }

    var posts []model.Post
    rows, err := db_client.DBClient.Query("SELECT id, title, description FROM products;")
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid request body",
        })
        return
    }

    for rows.Next(){
        var singlePost model.Post
        rows.Scan(&singlePost.ID, &singlePost.Title, &singlePost.Description)
        if singlePost.Title == reqBody.Title {
            c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{
                "error": true,
                "message": "Title already exists",
            })
            return
        }
        posts = append(posts, singlePost)
    }


    res, err := db_client.DBClient.Exec("INSERT INTO products (title, description) VALUES (?, ?);", 
        reqBody.Title,//"testing",
        reqBody.Description,//"Just testing something",
    )
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid request body2",
        })
        return
    }

    id, err := res.LastInsertId()
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid request body3",
        })
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{
        "error": false,
        "id": id,
    })
}

// GetProducts godoc
// @Summary get all books info
// @Description fetch all books from database
// @ID get-string-by-int
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  json
 
// @Router / [get]
func GetProducts(c *gin.Context){
    var posts []model.Post
    h := testHeader{}
    if err := c.ShouldBindHeader(&h); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Access denied",
        })
        return
    }
    if h.Token != "7b215b90-df8d-4077-8852-0907b0c1034e"{
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid Access",
        })
        return
    }
    rows, err := db_client.DBClient.Query("SELECT id, title, description FROM products;")
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid request body",
        })
        return
    }

    for rows.Next(){
        var singlePost model.Post
        if err := rows.Scan(&singlePost.ID, &singlePost.Title, &singlePost.Description); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
                "error": true,
                "message": "Invalid request body",
            })
            return
        }
        posts = append(posts, singlePost)
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, posts)
}

// GetSingleProduct godoc
// @Summary get a single book info
// @Description fetch a book from database by id
// @ID get-string-by-int
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  json
// @Param id path int true "Post ID"
 
// @Router /:id/show [get]
func GetSingleProduct(c *gin.Context){
    idStr := c.Param("id")
    id, _ := strconv.Atoi(idStr)
    h := testHeader{}
    if err := c.ShouldBindHeader(&h); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Access denied",
        })
        return
    }
    if h.Token != "7b215b90-df8d-4077-8852-0907b0c1034e"{
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid Access",
        })
        return
    }

    row := db_client.DBClient.QueryRow("SELECT id, title, description FROM products WHERE id = ?;", id)
    var post model.Post
    if err := row.Scan(&post.ID, &post.Title, &post.Description); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "something is wrong with request",
        })
        return
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, post)
}

// UpdateSingleProduct godoc
// @Summary get a books info
// @Description change info of a book
// @ID get-string-by-int
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  json
// // @Param id path int true "Post ID"

// @Router /:id/update [put]
func UpdateSingleProduct(c *gin.Context){
    var reqBody model.Post
    h := testHeader{}
    if err := c.ShouldBindHeader(&h); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Access denied",
        })
        return
    }
    if h.Token != "7b215b90-df8d-4077-8852-0907b0c1034e"{
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid Access",
        })
        return
    }
    idStr := c.Param("id")
    id, _ := strconv.Atoi(idStr)

    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&reqBody); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid request body",
        })
        return
    }

    if reqBody.Title == ""{
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Insert product title",
        })
        return
    }

    //checking if user changed the title value
    row := db_client.DBClient.QueryRow("SELECT id, title, description FROM products WHERE id = ?;", id)
    var post model.Post
    row.Scan(&post.ID, &post.Title, &post.Description)
    if post.Title != reqBody.Title {
        //user changed tille
        var posts []model.Post
        rows, _ := db_client.DBClient.Query("SELECT id, title, description FROM products;")

        for rows.Next(){
            var singlePost model.Post
            rows.Scan(&singlePost.ID, &singlePost.Title, &singlePost.Description)
            if singlePost.Title == reqBody.Title {
                c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{
                    "error": true,
                    "message": "Another product already has this title",
                })
                return
            }
            posts = append(posts, singlePost)
        }
    }
    


    _, err := db_client.DBClient.Exec("UPDATE products SET title = ?, description = ? WHERE id = ?;", 
        reqBody.Title,
        reqBody.Description,
        id,
    )
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid request body2",
        })
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{
        "error": false,
        "id": id,
        "newTitle": reqBody.Title,
        "newDescription": reqBody.Description,
    })

}

// DeleteSingleProduct godoc
// @Summary delete a book
// @Description remove a book from dataBase
// @ID get-string-by-int
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  json
// @Param id path int true "Post ID"

// @Router /:id/delete [delete]
func DeleteSingleProduct(c *gin.Context){
    idStr := c.Param("id")
    id, _ := strconv.Atoi(idStr)
    h := testHeader{}
    if err := c.ShouldBindHeader(&h); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Access denied",
        })
        return
    }
    if h.Token != "7b215b90-df8d-4077-8852-0907b0c1034e"{
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid Access",
        })
        return
    }

    _,err := db_client.DBClient.Exec("DELETE FROM products WHERE id = ?;", id)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid request body2",
        })
        return
    }
    
    var posts []model.Post
    rows, err := db_client.DBClient.Query("SELECT id, title, description FROM products;")
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid request body",
        })
        return
    }

    for rows.Next(){
        var singlePost model.Post
        if err := rows.Scan(&singlePost.ID, &singlePost.Title, &singlePost.Description); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
                "error": true,
                "message": "Invalid request body",
            })
            return
        }
        posts = append(posts, singlePost)
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, posts)
}
```

on the admin model

```
package model

// Admin example

type Admin struct {
    Id int64        `json: "id" example:"1"`
    Username string     `json: "username" example:"admin name"`
    Password string     `json: "password" example:"h56yggy7uj"`
}
```

my post model

```
package model

type Post struct {
    ID int64            `json: "id"`
    Title string        `json: "title"`
    Description *string     `json: "description"`
}
```

please I have no idea what I am doing wrong, I need help, as I want all information to display

Comment: does this work?
// @Success 200 {object} model.Post

Answer (score 0):

swagger uses comments to generate documentations and descriptions, there should be no space between the comment lines. All I did was delete the empty lines between the comments

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below article to get swagger on gin with description

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/tutorial-generate-swagger-specification-and-swaggerui-for-gin-go-web-framework-9f0c038483b5

If you face any issues to get swag use below command to get swag on windows

```
go install github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag
```